# Jenkinsfile two stages two testng results

Tags: jenkins, testng, jenkins-pipeline

I have one Jenkinsfile with two testing stages.

```
    stage("test 1") {
      dir("test 1") {


        git url: "repo"
        sh "${mvnHome}/bin/mvn -f pom.xml (...)"

        git url: "repo"
        sh "${mvnHome}/bin/mvn -f pom.xml (...)"

        step([$class: 'Publisher', reportFilenamePattern: "${workspace}/(path)/testng-results-mod.xml"])

      }
    }

    stage("test 2") {
      dir("test_2") {

        git url: "repo"
        sh "${mvnHome}/bin/mvn -f pom.xml (...)"

        git url: "repo"
        sh "${mvnHome}/bin/mvn -f pom.xml (...)"

        step([$class: 'Publisher', reportFilenamePattern: "${workspace}/(path)/testng-results-mod.xml"])

      }
    }
```

This is working fine. Both stages generates testng results file. But unfortunately i end up with just one xml result file, because first file is being overwriten by second test. Both test use same name.

There are two link in jenkins (build) to TestNG results, but they all lead to this same xml file. In build directory there is also just one file.

Is there any option to generate each test under different name? So they both will be avaliable in the end?

Answer (score 0):

Ok. So after testing... it looks like you can have multiple xml files in output directory. TestNG pluging is displaying them as one report.

So Ive just added option to rename output file to _1.xml and _2.xml and it works.

Comment: where did you added option to rename output file, please share. i am having similar problem